# Postgresql Error "Column does not exists" in UPDATE ... FROM statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I am trying to update the column of one table with values from another table using UPDATE ... SET in postgresql.

```
CREATE TABLE cars (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(40),
    model_id integer NOT NULL
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE models (
    id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    model_id integer NOT NULL
);
```

I want to fill cars.name from the names stored in models, using a "join" on model_id.

```
update cars as c
set c.name = m.name
from models as m
where m.model_id = c.model_id;
```

When executing this query, I see the following error:

```
FEHLER: Spalte »c« von Relation »cars « existiert nicht
```

This translates to `ERROR: Column >>c<< from relation >>cars<< does not exists`. I would be very grateful if any of you could spot my mistake or suggest a better way of achieving this goal.

One correction I tried is not using alias.

```
update cars
set cars.name = m.name
from models as m
where m.model_id = cars.model_id;
```

I still get the same error

```
FEHLER: Spalte »c« von Relation »cars« existiert nicht
```

This translates to `ERROR: Column >>cars << from relation >>cars<< does not exists`

Another query that I just tried is using explicit joins:

```
update c
set c.name = m.name
from cars c
join models m
on m.model_id= c.model_id
```

Error is now 'relation >>c<< does not exists'. But I lifted the idea from a mySQL example, so I didn't really think it would work...

Answer (score 0):

Your query could be:

```
update cars
set name = m.name
from models m
where m.model_id = cars.model_id;
```

**[DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2dLJiTeg)**

According to the [`UPDATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) docs:

> **`column_name`**
> ... Do not include the table's name in the specification of a target column — for example, `UPDATE table_name SET table_name.col = 1` is invalid.

Please look at [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/158631) too (as
@ypercubeᵀᴹ states, only one table can be updated in an UPDATE clause) and there is no need for table alias for the updatable table.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solves the problem :)

Comment: @BeanSalad glad to help. You can upvote if the answer is helpful or accept it.